# how to do continuous starting and stopping of scanning ble in android

Tags: android

For continuous scanning of advertising data, i tried in starting and stopping the mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback) function ,but still it is happening only once .when i tried to call the scanning twice, in logcat i can see that LE scan has already started ,as the second call is not executing . how to call repeated scanning and stopping here .

private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {

```
    if (enable){
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                System.out.println("hello");

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);
        System.out.println(SCAN_PERIOD);
        mScanning = true;

        System.out.println("starttt 1!");
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        //////

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                System.out.println("hello");

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);
        System.out.println(SCAN_PERIOD);
        mScanning = true;

        System.out.println("starttt 1!");
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    //////////


    }
    else
    {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works pretty well for me,

I have a method called `discoverBLEdevices`, which is called in `onCreate`.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void discoverBLEDevices() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     startScan.run();
     Log.e("BLE_Scanner", "DiscoverBLE");
}
```

I have a `startScan` `Runnable`, in which I start the scan and invoke another runnable to stop the scan as shown below :

```
private Runnable startScan = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scanHandler.postDelayed(stopScan, 500);
        mBLEAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        Log.e("BLE_Scanner", "Start Scan");
    }
};
```

After 500 msec I invoke a runnable called `stopScan` which stops the scanning and calls `startScan` runnable again.

```
private Runnable stopScan = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mBLEAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        scanHandler.postDelayed(startScan, 10);
        Log.e("BLE_Scanner", "Stop Scan");
    }
};
```

The callback which I have is as follows :

```
// Device scan callback.
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                byte[] scanRecord) {

            String Address = device.getAddress();
            String Name = device.getName();
            Log.e("mLeScanCallback",""+Address +" : "+Name);
        }
    };
```

The entire code :

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class BluetoothLE extends Service {

private BluetoothAdapter mBLEAdapter;
private BluetoothManager manager;
private Handler scanHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    turnonBLE();
    discoverBLEDevices();
 }

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void turnonBLE() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBLEAdapter = manager.getAdapter();
    mBLEAdapter.enable();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BTLE ON Service",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("BLE_Scanner", "TurnOnBLE");}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void discoverBLEDevices() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startScan.run();
    Log.e("BLE_Scanner", "DiscoverBLE");
}


private Runnable startScan = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scanHandler.postDelayed(stopScan, 500);
        mBLEAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
};


// Device scan callback.
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                byte[] scanRecord) {

            String Address = device.getAddress();
            String Name = device.getName();
            Log.e("mLeScanCallback",""+Address +" : "+Name);
            }
    };


private Runnable stopScan = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mBLEAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        scanHandler.postDelayed(startScan, 10);
    }
};
}
```

Comment: I know this is old but is there a reason for wanting to start and stop the scan like this versus running the scan continuously?

Answer (score 0):

In case it doesn't update, I added a few lines by turning on/turning off the Bluetooth adapter. Works fine in my case.

```
fun discoverBLEDevices(){
    startScan.run()
    Log.d("Scan", " Discover BLE")
}

private val startScan:Runnable = Runnable {
    scanHandler.postDelayed(stopScan,10000)
    bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(bleScanner)
    // bluetoothAdapter.enable()
    Log.e("BLE_Scanner", "Start Scan")
}

private val stopScan:Runnable = Runnable {
    bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(bleScanner)
    bluetoothAdapter.disable()
    bluetoothAdapter.enable()
    scanHandler.postDelayed(startScan, 1000)
    Log.e("BLE_Scanner", "Stop Scan")
}
```